# How to create multiple objects in serializers create method?

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload a csv file and then using it to populate a table in the database (creating multiple objects).

serializers.py:

```
def instantiate_batch_objects(data_list, user):
    return [
        WorkData(
            work=db_obj['work'],
            recordTime=db_obj['recordTime'],
            user=user
        ) for db_obj in data_list
    ]


class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filedata = serializers.FileField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkData
        fields = ['user', 'filedata']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        file = validated_data.pop('filedata')
        data_list = csv_file_parser(file)        
        batch = instantiate_batch_objects(data_list, validated_data['user'])
        work_data_objects = WorkData.objects.bulk_create(batch)
        # print(work_data_objects[0])
        return work_data_objects
```

views.py:

```
class FileUploadView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = WorkData.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    # I guess, this is not need for my case.
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs.get('data'))
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True

        return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

models.py

```
class WorkData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='work_data',
    )
    work = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    recordTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True)
```

When I upload the file and post it I get this error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `FileUploadSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance. Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'user'.

But I can see table is populated successfully in the database. What should I return from `create` method of `FileUploadSerializer`?

Comment: `FileUploadSerializer.create()` supposed to be retrun only a single model instance.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I need to create objects in bulk.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, BTW, you can return [multiple](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create)

Comment: can you add a snippet to the data you are passing to your endpoint?

Comment: I am passing a file to the api endpoint. Then reading data from the file and creating objects overriding serializer class create method.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you are not passing a user foregin key value along with this file in the request?

Comment: anyway the problem happens because you are using ModelSerializer not ListSerializer, thats why returing a list of objects is giving you this error.

Comment: @MahmoudAdel This api will be called on authentication so user is passed along with the file when calling api

Comment: @MahmoudAdel On using ListSerializer I am getting ``child` is a required argument` error. To be honest I really don't have any idea how to properly use it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after trying an example myself I was able to reproduce the errors, I have a better understanding of why this is happing now.

First, let's put the implementation of create() on the view class here

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

The original error of `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field user`... etc happened because the `create()` in the `FileUploadView` is returning `serializer.data` which is expecting fields `user` and `filedata` but `create()` on `FileUploadSerializer` is returning a **list of objects** so you can see now why this is happening.

You can solve this by overriding `create()` on `FileUploadView` and serialize the returned serializer data  with a `WorkDataSerializer` that you will create

For ex:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        workData = WorkDataSerializer(data=serializer.data)
        return Response(workData.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

OR, you can do it on serializer level - which I prefer -

For example:

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filedata = serializers.FileField(write_only=True)
    created_objects_from_file = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        
    def get_created_objects_from_file(self, obj):
       file = self.validated_data.pop('filedata')
       data_list = csv_file_parser(file)        
       batch = instantiate_batch_objects(data_list, self.validated_data['user'])
       work_data_objects = WorkData.objects.bulk_create(batch)
       
       return WorkDataSerializer(work_data_objects, many = True).data
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = WorkData
        fields = ['user', 'filedata']



class WorkDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
         # fields of WorkData model you want to return
```

This should work with no problems, note that `SerializerMethodField` is read_only by default

see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: My upvote for finding the problem. I too figured it out and the naive solution came to my mind is to just return one object from list: `return work_data_objects[0]`.

Comment: I assumed that returning all the created objects is mandatory or something, glad that you figured it out.

Comment: I will update my previouse answer so nobody get confused later

Comment: No, it wasn't. But looking for a clean solution right now. It would be great if you can put solution using `ListSerialzer`.

Comment: I would suggest please test your solution and post it only after it works. I can see lots of errors in second solution.

Comment: I have already done that, why should I post a sol which I'm not sure about?

Comment: this will add `created_objects_from_file`  field to the resulted JSON which has a list of all the created objects

Comment: How are you accessing `validated_data` in `get_created_objects_from_file`?

Comment: sorry about that, I tested the flow, not the exact same code as it depends on your logic, will update the answer